# s3api put-object with spaces included in the name of the file

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am trying to upload files to S3 in order to get some redirects working.
Unfortunately I notice some anomalies when the file names have spaces.

My bash script is very simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
declare -A redirects
redirects["foo/bar/index.html"]="/foo/"
redirects["foo/bar/test.pdf"]="/foo/test.pdf"
redirects["assets/docs/NEW-TEST WELCOME TO MYTEST.pdf"]="/"

for i in "${!redirects[@]}" 
do
    echo "Executing command: aws s3api put-object --bucket $BUCKET_NAME --key" '"'${i}'"' "--website-redirect-location" "${redirects[$i]}"
    aws s3api put-object --bucket $BUCKET_NAME --key '"'${i}'"' --website-redirect-location "${redirects[$i]}"
done
```

From the output what I can see is:

```
Executing command: aws s3api put-object --bucket myamazingbucket --key "assets/docs/NEW-TEST WELCOME TO MYTEST.pdf" --website-redirect-location /
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help

Unknown options: TO, MYTEST.pdf", WELCOME
```

Do you have suggestions on how to make these put-objects on S3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying `'"'${i}'"'` you are forcing a literal quote at the beginning and end of the string, which internally results in an aws command like:

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket BUCKET_NAME --key '"assets/docs/NEW-TEST' WELCOME TO 'MYTEST.pdf"' --website-redirect-location /
```

Instead, you should properly quote your string, changing your `aws` command line to:

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket $BUCKET_NAME --key "${i}" --website-redirect-location "${redirects[$i]}"
```

... which internally results in an aws command like below.

```
aws s3api put-object --bucket BUCKET_NAME --key 'assets/docs/NEW-TEST WELCOME TO MYTEST.pdf' --website-redirect-location /
```

Btw. your `echo` command behaves differently because you're passing the quoted command line to `echo` as a quoted string.

Comment: Great. Thank you :)